# Is there a way to use gmail in nodemailer which will work perfectly?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I turned on the "less secure apps" on my account and tested the app. It was working fine, but when I used someone else's GMAIL credentials it didn't work.

There is no problem when using private mail or any other service.